# Problema con el llamado Prefligth

Tags: nodejs, reactjs

estoy nuevo en NodeJs, cree varias APIs para mi aplicacion con distintos metodos y todas funcionan bien, el tema esta en que cree una API nueva en el mismo archivo donde tengo las demas pero al llamarla desde mi FE se llama dos veces una es prefligth con metodo options y otra queda pending pero sin metodo... Adjunto capturas..[image: Captura de la consola del llamado de la API]

```
    router.put("/carrousel-item/update/:id", fileUpload, (req, res) => {
     req.getConnection((err, conn) => {
    try {
      const image = fs.readFileSync(
        path.join(__dirname, "../images/" + req.file.filename)
      );
      const title_en = req.body.title_en;
      const title_es = req.body.title_es;
      const sub_title_color_1_en = req.body.sub_title_color_1_en;
      const sub_title_color_1_es = req.body.sub_title_color_1_es;
      const sub_title_color_2_en = req.body.sub_title_color_2_en;
      const sub_title_color_2_es = req.body.sub_title_color_2_es;
      try {
        conn.query(
          `UPDATE home_team_section SET ? WHERE id = ?`,
          [
            {
              title_en: title_en,
              title_es: title_es,
              sub_title_color_1_en: sub_title_color_1_en,
              sub_title_color_1_es: sub_title_color_1_es,
              sub_title_color_2_en: sub_title_color_2_en,
              sub_title_color_2_es: sub_title_color_2_es,
              image: image,
            },
          ],
          (err, rows) => {
            res.send(rows);
          }
        );
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
     } catch (error) {}
    });
   });
```

Este problema no me esta dejando avanzar con el proyecto ya que no me deja ejecutar ninguna API nueva

Nota: Tengo anadido el cors()

Comment: Has probado a debuggear? Qué error devuelve?

Comment: Que te devuelve el preflight? Dices que queda pendiente, eventualmente se resolvería, qué resultado da cuando se resuelve? Puedes adjuntar de igual forma la información de la HTTP request real que se realiza?